# Magento 2: How to get special price from the order?

Tags: magento2, special-price

**Question:** I need to know if a product is bought with special price or not.

**More Background:**
We are using three prices for our products, which are *original price*, *special price* and *tier price*. We have integrated Magento with another system, called *Linx*. This system needs to know if the price is a special price, or not.

When I look at the `sales_order_item` table, I can list the following fields related with the price:

- price
- base_price
- original_price
- base_original_price
- price_incl_tax
- base_price_incl_tax
- discount_percent
- discount_amount

**Paraphrased Question:** How can I say that one of these fields hold `special price` for sure?

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ....
}
```

use below code in function where you want to get price

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $price = $item->getPrice(); //discount price
}
```

Comment: I think I need to be more clear. How can I be sure that this is not a tier price? `$item->getPrice()` is the price that customer paid. But can we confirm that if it is special price, or not?